# Photo url in ajax request using Carrierwave

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, rails-activerecord, carrierwave

I have an API that's requested through ajax. The query returns a collection that is serialized into json before rendering back to the client. Each record has assigned a photo url by Carrierwave. Nothing special.

In rails console I get the full complete public url of each photo to google cloud storage, however, in the response (client side), from the array of objects, I get "uploads/...". I need the complete url (like from the console) to be parsed to the json returned.

How do I do this?

controller.rb

```
def get_filtered
  ...
  # query is performed
  ...
  render json: filtered_properties.as_json
end
```

on javascript:

```
...
properties = response.data
properties[0].photos[0].url // => "uploads/property/photos/photo1.jpg"
```

whereas on rails console I get the complete public url to my google cloud storage folder.

Comment: Post your code @jasa

Comment: @Prashant4224 there's the relevant part of the code bugging me

Comment: are you sure filtered_properties contains the complete url? and you haven't overridden the `as_json` call?

Comment: @Minato I did not overrode as_json

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it explicitly:

config/envrionments/[environment].rb

```
config.asset_host = 'http://example.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

So my solution was to use [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) gem that lets an easy manipulation of the json response. Here's a [video](http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers?autoplay=true) by Ryan Bates on it.